# Microsoft Access VBA Create Public-Folder Subfolder

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba, exchange-server

I'm looking for some advice on Microsoft Access VBA - Basically, I have been asked to create a button on a form, upon this button being clicked it will display a box asking for a folder name (I can manually type in, then click 'Ok') which will then create a subfolder in a public folder within Outlook/Exchange 2013.

Any information / advice on this would be fantastic. I have tried some examples on the Internet but my VBA knowledge doesn't allow me to amend the code for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

No doubt this code can be tidied up.  It will create a folder called 'New One' within the Inbox.
You'll need to update the code to point to the correct folder and ask for the new name.

```
Sub CreateFolder()

        Dim oOutlook As Object          'Outlook.Application
        Dim nNameSpace As Object        'Outlook.Namespace
        Dim oFolder As Object

        Dim sFolder As String
        sFolder = "Mailbox - Bill Gates\Inbox"

        Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set nNameSpace = oOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

        Set oFolder = GetFolderPath(sFolder)
        oFolder.Folders.Add "New One" 'Add the 'New One' folder to the Inbox.

    End Sub

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Procedure : GetFolderPath
    ' Author    : Diane Poremsky
    ' Date      : 09/06/2015
    ' Original  : http://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/
    ' Purpose   :
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Function GetFolderPath(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Object 'Outlook.Folder

        Dim oOutlook As Object          'Outlook.Application
        Dim nNameSpace As Object        'Outlook.Namespace

        Dim oFolder As Object 'Outlook.Folder
        Dim FoldersArray As Variant
        Dim i As Integer

        On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error

        Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
            FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
        End If
        FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
        Set oFolder = oOutlook.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
        If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
            For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
                Dim SubFolders As Object
                Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
                Set oFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
                If oFolder Is Nothing Then
                    Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
                End If
            Next
        End If
        Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
        Exit Function

    GetFolderPath_Error:
        Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Shell command in VBA. You can execute DOS commands to make folders. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278437%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: I think you missed the `Outlook/Exchange 2013` part.

Comment: Yep I did. Please don't downvote me. I have kids to feed.

Comment: Hahaha :-) You are aware that you can delete your answer? @Delmer